# way to override a method

Tags: java, overriding

I my superclass I have a method:

```
public void addController(ActionListener controller)
{
    button.addActionListener(controller);
}
```

in the derived class I have to implement `addController` adding `button.setActionCommand("something");` I have to override the method `addcontroller()` or add simply `super()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

If you want to **Implement the method in Super class, and also want to add button.setActionCommand("something"), then do this..**

By **adding the super call in the addController along with your setActionCommand**

```
public void addController(ActionListener controller)
{
    super.addController(controller)
    button.setActionCommand("something");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

```
@Override
public void addController(ActionListener controller)
{
    super.addController(controller)
    button.setActionCommand("something");
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void addController(ActionListener controller)
{
    button.addActionListener(controller);
    button.setActionCommand("something");
}
```

performance will be similar in both.